# How to add Special Character to Wifi SSID?

Tags: javascript, router, wifi

I want to know how can I add special char to my wifi ssid.I tried a post with similar question on reddit:[Reddit Link:](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5zcb8m/can_you_help_me_allow_my_router_to_accept_as_the/)

But In my case(Tenda N3) the source code was residing in the folder named "MainFrame(Wireless_basic.asp)>js>Gozila.js"

Every time I try to add any Symbol for Eg:"☣->&#x2623:",It give me an Error of :"Please specify a valid SSID between 1-32 ASCII characters!"

I'm wondering if there is any way by which I can alter the 'gozila.js' file to remove that pop up or Error.

I already tried the method suggested by reddit post that I mentioned previously but i couldn't find any function like 'function validate_ssidchar' and I also tried disabling the js in the browser but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Please ignore my grammatical mistakes and The code give below is from gozila.js:

```html
function macsCheck(I,s){
    var m =/([0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/;
    if(I.length!=17 || !m.test(I)){
        alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [s]));
        I.value = I.defaultValue;
        return false
    }
    return true
}

function toNextMac(f, obj, nextIndex){
 obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '');
 if(obj.value.length === 2 && nextIndex) {
  nextIndex = parseInt(nextIndex, 10);
  f.elements[obj.id][nextIndex].focus();
 }
}
function ill_check(val, ill_array, str) {
 var i = 0;
 for(; i< ill_array.length; i++) {
  if (val.indexOf(ill_array[i]) != -1) {
   alert( _( "Pleale specify a valid %s! Invalid characters include %s!", [str, ill_array[i]] ) );
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

function isNumber(val, label) {
 var t = /^[0-9]{1,}$/;
 if (!t.test(val)) {
  alert(_("Please specify a valid %s!",[label]));
  return false;
 }
 return true ;
}

function rangeCheck(elem, min, max, label) {
 var val = elem.value;
 
 if (!isNumber(val, label)) {
  return false;
 }
 if ((val < min) || (val > max)) { 
  alert(_("%s beyond the range!", [label])) ;
  elem.value = elem.defaultValue ;
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}

function chkStrLen(s,m,M,msg){
 var str = s.value;
 if (str.length < m || str.length > M ){
  alert(_("%s the length is not within the range!",[msg]));
  return false;
 }
    return true;
}
//add by stanley
function ipCheck(srcip,dstip,mask) {
   var sip = srcip.split('.'),
  dip = dstip.split('.'),
  lanmsk = mask.split('.');
 if(sip[0] == dip[0]){
  if(sip[0]<128 && lanmsk[1] == "0")
   return true; 
 }else{
  return false;
 }
 
 if(sip[1] == dip[1]){
  if(sip[0]<192 && lanmsk[2] == "0")
   return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }

 if(sip[2] == dip[2]){
  if(sip[0]<224 && lanmsk[3] == "0")
   return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
}
//end


function refresh(destination) {
   window.location = destination ;  
}

function decomList(str,len,idx,dot) {  
 var t = str.split(dot);
 return t[idx];
}


function verifyIP0(ipa,msg) {
 var ip=combinIP2(ipa);
 if (ip=='' || ip=='0.0.0.0'){
  return true;
 }
 return verifyIP2(ipa,msg);
}
function verifyIP2(ipa, msg, subnet) {
 var tip = /^[0-9]{1,}$/,
  ip = [],
  invalid_msg = _("Please enter a valid %s!", [msg]),
  contains_invalid = _("Please specify a valid %s!", [msg]),
  i;
 if (ipa.length==4){
  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
   ip[i]=ipa[i].value;
  }
 } else {
  ip = ipa.value.split(".");
 }

 if(ip.length != 4){
  alert(invalid_msg);
  return false;
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  if(!tip.test(ip[i])){
   alert(contains_invalid) ;
   return 0;
  }
 }
 if(ip[0] == 0 || ((ip[0] == 127) && (ip[3] == 0))){
  alert(invalid_msg);
  return false; 
 }
 if(ip[1] == "" || ip[2] == ""){
  alert(invalid_msg);
  return false; 
 }
 
 if(ip[1] == " " || ip[2] == " "){
  alert(invalid_msg);
  return false; 
 }

 if(ip[0] >=224) {
  alert(invalid_msg);
  return false;
 }
 
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        d = ip[i];
        if (d < 256 && d >= 0) {
   if (i != 3 || subnet == 1){
    continue;
   } else {
     if (d != 255 && d !=0 )
    continue;
   }
      
        } 
        alert(invalid_msg);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function clearInvalidIpstr(ipa) {
 var ip = [],
  i;
 if(ipa == ""){
  return ipa; 
 }
 ip=ipa.split(".");
 if(ip.length<4){
  return parseInt(ipa,10).toString(); 
 }
 for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
  var tmp = parseInt(ip[i],10);
  ip[i] = tmp.toString();
 }
 ipa=ip[0]+'.'+ip[1]+'.'+ip[2]+'.'+ip[3];
 return ipa; 
}


function decomMAC2(ma,macs,nodef) {
    var re = /^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$/,
  d;
    if (re.test(macs)||macs=='') {
  if (ma.length!=6) {
   ma.value=macs;
   return true;
  }
  if (macs!='') {
   d=macs.split(":");
  } else {
   d=['','','','','',''];
  }
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ma[i].value = d[i];
   if (!nodef) {
    ma[i].defaultValue = d[i];
   }
  }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function decomIP2(ipa,ips,nodef) {
    var re = /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/,
  d;
    if (re.test(ips)) {
        d =  ips.split(".");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ipa[i].value=d[i];
   if (!nodef) ipa[i].defaultValue=d[i];
  }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function combinIP2(d) {
 var ip;
 if (d.length!=4) {
  return d.value;
 }
    ip=d[0].value+"."+d[1].value+"."+d[2].value+"."+d[3].value;
    if (ip == "...") {
        ip="";
 }
    return ip;
}
function combinMAC2(m) {
    var mac = m[0].value.toUpperCase()+":"+m[1].value.toUpperCase()+":"+ 
   m[2].value.toUpperCase()+":"+m[3].value.toUpperCase()+":"+
   m[4].value.toUpperCase()+":"+m[5].value.toUpperCase();
    if (mac==":::::"){
        mac="";
 }
    return mac;
}

function ipMskChk(mn,str){
 var t = /^[0-9]{1,}$/,
  m = [],
  f = 0,
  v;
 if (mn.length === 4) {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   m[i] = mn[i].value;
  }
 } else {
  m=mn.value.split('.');
  if (m.length!=4) {
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str]));
   return 0;
  }
 }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  if(!t.test(m[i])){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!",[str])) ; return 0;
  }
 }
 v = (m[0]<<24)|(m[1]<<16)|(m[2]<<8)|(m[3]);
  
    **for (k=0;k<32;k++) {
  if ((v>>k)&1) {
   f = 1;
  } else if (f==1){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str])) ;
   return 0 ;
  }
 }**
 if (f==0) {
  alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str]));
  return 0;
 }
 return 1 ;
}

function Cfg(i,n,v){
 this.i = i;
    this.n = n;
    this.v = this.o = v;
}

var CA = [];

function addCfg(n,i,v) {
 CA.length++;
    CA[CA.length-1]= new Cfg(i,n,v);
}

function idxOfCfg(kk) {
    if (typeof kk == "undefined") {
  alert(_("not defined"));
  return -1;
 }
    for (var i=0; i< CA.length;i++) {
        if (typeof CA[i].n != "undefined" && CA[i].n == kk )
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function getCfg(n) {
 var idx = idxOfCfg(n)
 if ( idx >=0) {
  return CA[idx].v;
 } else {
  return "";
 }
}

function setCfg(n,v) {
 var idx = idxOfCfg(n)
 if ( idx >=0) {
  CA[idx].v = v ;
 }
}

//从配置解析到表单
function cfg2Form(f) {
 var e;
    for (var i=0;i < CA.length;i++){
        e = f[CA[i].n];
        if (e) {
   if (typeof e.name == "undefined" &&  typeof e[0].name == "undefined"){
    continue;
   }
   
   if (e.length && e[0].type == "text") {
    if (e.length==4) {
     decomIP2(e,CA[i].v);
    } else if (e.length==6) {
     decomMAC2(e,CA[i].v);
    }
   } else if (e.length && e[0].type == "radio") {
    for (var j=0;j < e.length;j++) {
     e[j].checked = e[j].defaultChecked = (e[j].value == CA[i].v);
    }
   } else if (e.type=="checkbox") {
    e.checked=e.defaultChecked=Number(CA[i].v);
   } else if (e.type=="select-one" || e.type=="select") {
    /*  document.getElementById(e.id).value = CA[i].v;
                    e.value = CA[i].v;*/
    for (var j=0;j<e.options.length;j++) {
     e.options[j].selected = (e.options[j].value==CA[i].v);
    }
   } else {
    e.value=getCfg(e.name);
   }
   if (e.defaultValue != "undefined") {
    e.defaultValue = e.value;
   }
  }
    }
}

//从表单提交到配置
var frmExtraElm='';
function form2Cfg(f){
 var e;
    for (var i=0;i<CA.length;i++){
        e = f[CA[i].n];
  if (e) {
   if (e.disabled) continue;
   if ( e.length && e[0].type=="text" ) {
    if (e.length==4) CA[i].v=combinIP2(e);
    else if (e.length==6) CA[i].v=combinMAC2(e);
   } else if ( e.length && e[0].type=="radio") {
    for (var j=0;j<e.length;j++) {
     if (e[j].checked) {
      CA[i].v=e[j].value;
      break;
     }
    }
   }
   else
   if (e.type=="checkbox")
    setCfg(e.name, Number(e.checked) );
   else
    setCfg(e.name, e.value);
  }
    }
}

function fit2(n) {
 var s = String(n+100).substr(1,2);
 return s;
}

function timeStr(t){
 if (t < 0) {
  str = '00:00:00';
  return str;
 }
 var s=t%60,
  m=parseInt(t/60)%60,
  h=parseInt(t/3600)%24,
  d=parseInt(t/86400),
  str='';
 
 if (d > 999) {
  return _("Permanent");
 }
 if (d) {
  str +=d+_("Day(s)");
 }
 str += fit2(h) + ':';
 str += fit2(m) + ':';
 str += fit2(s);
 return str;
}

function rmEntry(a,i){
 if (a.splice) {
  a.splice(i,1);
 } else {
  if (i>=a.length) {
   return;
  }
  for (var k=i+1;k<=a.length;k++){
   a[k-1]=a[k];
  }
  a.length--;
 }
}

//1
function checkText(str) {
 var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/;
 if (str === "") {
  return true;
 }
 return re.test(str);
}

//1 mac_clone
function CheckMAC(mac) { 
 var re = /^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$/;
    if (!re.test(mac)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


//1mac_tc
//mac ip url 过滤 初始�?
function init2(f) {
 var n = getCfg("curNum");
 if(n == "") {
  n = 1;
 }
  
 if(getCfg("check_en") == 1) {
  document.getElementById("check").checked = true;
 } else {
  document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
 }
 onCheck();

 f.curNum.selectedIndex = n-1;
 onChangeNum(f);
}

//异步传输生成对象
function GetReqObj(){
 var req = null; 
 try{
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(req.overrideMimeType) {
   req.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
  }
 } catch (trymicrosoft){
  try {
   req = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (othermicrosoft) {
   try {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (failed) {
    req = false;
   }
  }
  } 
 if(!req) {
  alert("Error initializing HttpRequest!");
  return false;
 } 
 return req;
}

function IsReboot() {
 if(confirm(_("Reboot the router to bring the settings into effect ,reboot now?"))) { 
  return 1;
 } else {
  return 0;
 }
}

function ckRemark(s) {
 var re = /^\w{0,}$/;
 if(!re.test(remark)) {
  alert(_("Please specify a valid policy name that include alphanumeric characters or underscore!"));
  return false;
 } 
 return true;
}

function ckMacReserve(mac){
 var m = mac.split(":"); 
 for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
  m[i] = m[i].toUpperCase();
 }
 if(m =="00:00:00:00:00:00" || m == "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF") {
  alert(_("The MAC address belongs to reserved addresses, please re-enter!")) ;
  return false;
 }
 
 if(parseInt(m[0],16)&1 == 1) {//m[0]最后一位是否为1{
  alert(_("The MAC address belongs to multicast addresses, please re-enter!")) ;
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

function show_hide(el,shownow) {
 document.getElementById(el).style.display = (shownow) ? '' : 'none' ;
}

function tenda_ipMskChk(mn,str,lanip) {
 var m = [],
  lanipi =[],
  t = /^[0-9]{1,}$/,
  f = 0;
 if (mn.length==4) {
  for (i=0;i<4;i++){
   m[i]=mn[i].value;
  }
 } else {
  m=mn.value.split('.');
  if (m.length!=4) { alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str])) ; return 0; }
 }
 for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
  if(!t.test(m[i])) {
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!",[str]));
   return 0;
  }
 }
//add end

 var v=(m[0]<<24)|(m[1]<<16)|(m[2]<<8)|(m[3]);
  
    **for (k=0;k<32;k++){
  if ((v>>k)&1){
   f = 1;
  } else if (f==1){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str])) ;
   return 0 ;
  }
 }**
 if (f==0) { alert(_("Please enter a valid %s!", [str])) ; return 0; }
//add by stanley
 lanipi = lanip.value.split('.');
 if(lanipi[0]<128) {
  if(m[0]<255){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  }
  if(m[1]>0 || m[2]>0 || m[3]>0){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  } 
 }else if(lanipi[0]<192){
  if(m[0]<255 || m[1]< 255 ){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  }
  if( m[2]>0 || m[3]>0){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  } 
 }else if(lanipi[0]<224){
  if(m[0]<255 || m[1]< 255 || m[2]< 255){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  }
  if( m[3]>0){
   alert(_("Please enter a valid %s. The VLSM and CIDR can not be supported.", [str]));
   return 0;
  } 
 }
//end
 return 1 ;
}
function  detectCapsLock(event){  
    var e = event||window.event, 
  o = e.target||e.srcElement,  
  oTip = o.nextSibling,  
  keyCode  =  e.keyCode||e.which; 
 if ( keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90){
  oTip.style.display = '';
  setTimeout(function () {
   document.getElementById("uCL").style.display = 'none';
  },1000);
 } else {
  oTip.style.display = 'none';
 } 
}

function showSaveMassage(){
 var div = document.getElementById("save");
 
 if (div) {
  div.className = "";
 } else {
  div = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById("body")[0].appendChild(div);
 }
 div.innerHTML = _('Configurations Saved!');
 setTimeout(function () {
  var div = document.getElementById("save");
  div.className = "none";
 }, 1000);
}

function Click(){ 
 window.event.returnValue=false; 
} 
document.oncontextmenu = Click; 

function tbl_tail_str(button){
 var m='<table width="75%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="40">&nbsp;';
 if (button!=''){
  m+=button;
     m+='</td></tr>';
 }
 m+='</table>';
 return m;
}
function tbl_tail(button){
 document.write(tbl_tail_str(button));
}
function tbl_tail_save(f){
 var m = '<div class="btn-group">';
 m += '<input type="button" class="btn" value="Ok" onClick=preSubmit('+f+')>';
 m += '<input type="button" class="btn last" value="Cancel" onClick=init(' + f + ')>';
 m += '</div>';
 document.write(m);
}
**function checkSSID(SSID)
{  
 var ascii = /^[ -~]+$/g;
 if(SSID == "" || SSID.length > 32 || !ascii.test(SSID)) {
  alert("Please specify a valid SSID between 1-32 ASCII characters!")
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}**
function decodeSSID(SSID){
    var e = document.createElement("div"),
  deSSID = '';
    e.innerHTML = SSID.replace(/\x20/g,"\xA0");
 if(e.innerText){
  deSSID = e.innerText;
 } else if (e.textContent) {
  deSSID = e.textContent;
 }
    e = null;
    return deSSID.replace(/\xA0/g,"\x20");
}
```

Comment: record ajax call (or generic post) in browser developer tools (while using "valid" SSID name) and copy it(request) "as CURL" to be run from command line. Then you can tweak it(payload of request) and avoid client-side validation by invoking such request from your console. But there is a huge chance  that server-side will reject it. Also some of devices will not be able to connect to such access point. Please remove unrelated tag "php".

Comment: well that look like a very daunting task to me bc i've never heard of these things before like ajax call and CURL.Is there any tutorial on the web related to what you told me "recording ajax call"

Comment: [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476095/using-curl-with-angularjs-and-bash)

Comment: I successfully added the request to  CL now how can I tweak it?

Comment: Some people for sure have "Tenda N3" but I do not own one so I can't check and make suggestion. Please add "captured" working command for curl into your question. Then we could tell you what needs to be tweaked.